# You need to enable JavaScript to run this app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have developed an api with node and mongo.

When ever i try to access my api  i get the error"You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Although the javascript is enabled for browser, i get the same error in postman as well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="./../src/js/index.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="PWA Splash">
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-1136x1136.png"
        media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-1294x1294.png"
        media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-2048x2048.png"
        media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-2148x2148.png"
        media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-2224x2224.png"
        media="(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-2436x2436.png"
        media="(min-device-width: 834px) and (max-device-width: 834px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-2732x2732.png"
        media="(min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./icons/pwa_/iOS/icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="images/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#6F6F6F">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00aba9">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.acf24367.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
        !function(l){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],f=0,i=[];f<n.length;f++)t=n[f],p[t]&&i.push(p[t][0]),p[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(l[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);i.length;)i.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,u||[]),a()}function a(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==p[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},p={1:0},c=[];function f(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return l[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,f),r.l=!0,r.exports}f.m=l,f.c=t,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=f(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)f.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var r=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;a()}([])
    </script>
    <script src="/static/js/2.818f941b.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.d7999e45.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your browser must have disabled Javascript. You can enable it by going into settings

Comment: How was that error delivered to the browser?  You app is returning that response to the browser, right?  Is that in the `noscript` section of a `text/html` response? Are _react_ or _create-react-app_ involved?

Comment: I found that the issue is from my node API, as when I give a call from postman to node api it produces the same error.

Comment: I have edited the question and put through the whole error.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the port is the correct one. I had a similar issue, my node (express) server was on port 8000 and my react client was on port 3000. The client was proxied to the server, both on localhost. I was requesting http://localhost:3000/somedata (and was getting a "You need to enable Javascript to run this app"), but I actually to see the data, I had only to type http://localhost:8000/somedata to see it in browser.

I know this post is rather old, but in case it helps someone...